# Why am I getting Error retrieving mongo document in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have inserted a document into a collection in MongoDB

```
public class Product :BaseDocument, IProduct
    {
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public List<IProductDetail> ProductDetailList { get; set; } = new List<IProductDetail>();
    }

public class ProductDetail:IProductDetail
        {
            public Guid ProductDetailId { get; set; }
            public string ProductDetailCode { get; set; }
        }
```

When I try to retrieve this though, I get an error

```
public List<IProduct> GetProductsList(Guid accountId)
        {
            IEnumerable<IProduct> prodList = new List<Product>();
            IMongoCollection<Product> products = _database.GetCollection<Product>("Products");
            prodList = products.Find(m => m.AccountId == accountId).ToList();
            return prodList.ToList();
        }
```

The error is as follows

> System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the
>   ProductDetailList property of class Entities.ProductDetail: Unknown
>   discriminator value 'ProductDetail'.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting this error is that MongoDB .NET driver doesn't know how to resolve `IProductDetail` and it tries to instantiate `ProductDetail` class since there is a `_t` field representing that type stored in MongoDB.

Usually you can use `BsonKnownTypes` in that kind of [polymorphic scenario](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/) but it works only for classes and structs. So if you want to preserve some class hierarchy here then you need to introduce an abstract class and apply this attribute there.

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ProductDetail))]
public abstract class ProductDetailBase: IProductDetail
{
}

public class ProductDetail : ProductDetailBase
{
    public Guid ProductDetailId { get; set; }
    public string ProductDetailCode { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can use:

```
public List<ProductDetailBase> ProductDetailList { get; set; } = new List<ProductDetailBase>();
```

In such case you can have a class hierarchy and MongoDB .NET driver will deserialize your BSON document into appropriate child class in runtime.

Comment: Thanks. This works. It does make everything very messy though... Is there a better way of doing this? ie working with the BSON Objects?

Comment: @coolblue2000 this really depends on what you're trying to achieve. When I see interfaces I'm assuming that you need some kind of polymorphism and you want to store a class hierarchy under single field. If so please read the article I linked - it deeply describes this area. Interface in .NET is something "vritual" whereas the type you're trying to serialize/deserialize in Mongo has to know how to resolve to concrete class so you can't use interface as a property type but when you need a hierarchy (polymorphism) then you can leverage `BsonKnownTypes`